# How to get a nice alignat of this equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to align this equation. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B + \cdots +  B^{n-1} \right)&=& A^{n}+& A^{n-1}\cdot B + \cdots + A\cdot B^{n-1},\\
B\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B + \cdots +  B^{n-1}\right)&=& & A^{n-1}\cdot B+ \cdots + A\cdot B^{n-1}+B^n.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, I see, at right hand side of the firt equation, after the sign `=` of the first letter A  is lower than sign `=` and the second A is too close the sign `+`. How can I repair it?

EDIT. I add `\,\,` after letters A

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B + \cdots +  B^{n-1} \right)&=& \,\,A^{n}+& \,\,A^{n-1}\cdot B + \cdots + A\cdot B^{n-1},\\
B\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B + \cdots +  B^{n-1}\right)&=& & \,\, A^{n-1}\cdot B+ \cdots + A\cdot B^{n-1}+B^n.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real need for multiple alignment points via `alignat` here, as you can insert a `\phantom` to achieve the appropriate gap in the lower equation using `align` only:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A \cdot \bigl(A^{n-1} + A^{n-2} \cdot B + \cdots + B^{n-1} \bigr) &= 
             A^n +    A^{n-1} \cdot B + \cdots + A \cdot B^{n-1}, \\
  B \cdot \bigl(A^{n-1} + A^{n-2} \cdot B + \cdots + B^{n-1} \bigr) &= 
    \phantom{A^n +{}} A^{n-1} \cdot B + \cdots + A \cdot B^{n-1} + B^n.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think there's no need to use `\bigl` `\bigr` here, but that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an additional (empty) column, in order to reach another left aligned one; also `+{}` is necessary for getting the correct space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A\cdot(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\dots+B^{n-1})&=A^{n}+{}&& A^{n-1}\cdot B+\dots+A\cdot B^{n-1},\\
B\cdot(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\dots+B^{n-1})&=        && A^{n-1}\cdot B+\dots+A\cdot B^{n-1}+B^n.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\left` and `\right` are redundant and that `\cdots` should be `\dots`.

[image]

Actually, I'd remove also all `\cdot` commands; unless they're needed to denote some non standard operation, they add nothing to clarity if they denote a standard multiplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2} B+\dots+B^{n-1})&=A^{n}+{}&& A^{n-1} B+\dots+A B^{n-1},\\
B(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2} B+\dots+B^{n-1})&=        && A^{n-1} B+\dots+A B^{n-1}+B^n.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]